# Freescale Symphony Studio doesn't complete the installation

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm going crazy.  I have to install Freescale Symphony Studio IDE for a university project but I can't. 
This program runs under Windows XP.

I have already Java installed and then I try to instal Symphony Studio.
The error after the installation is (the first part of the log file):

```
    !SESSION 2012-12-11 14:33:18.671 -----------------------------------------------      
    eclipse.buildId=M20070212-1330 java.version=1.7.0_09 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation                           
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US Command-line arguments: -  
    os win32   -ws win32 -arch x86
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2012-12-11 14:33:13.687 !MESSAGE   
    FrameworkEvent.ERROR !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not  
    be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-  
    1.0/Foundation-1.0,J2SE-1.3 at     
    org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:329)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:573)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:495)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:455)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:189)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:291)
```

.....

I don't know what do I have to do. I've also written to the Freescale Support but nobody answered me correctly.

I hope i can get some help,  thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:
Symphony Studio only works with JRE 1.5
So get JRE 1.5 and install it into the Symphony Studio directory.
Then Symphony will use this version of JRE.
More here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F